# DNS Records: point only files to a server ip, keep emails on the other one

Tags: email, dns, web-hosting, server, cname

So i have this two servers that i need to configure:

-Server s1 is on hostpappa (shared)

-Server s2 is a vps i own

What i need to do is **keep emails hosted on s1** and the **website hosted on s2**. What i tried was to change A record from mydomain.com to point to s2, but emails didn't work anymore. Is there any way i can do this with dns records?

After the first attempt failed, i tried to create on s2 a cname email.mydomain.com pointing to s1 ip and adding a mx record to this newly created cname. This failed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want:

1. An A record for mydomain.com pointing at the IP address for s2,
2. An MX record for mydomain.com pointing at the hostname of your email server.

The MX record in 2 should not point to a CNAME (this violates the requirement of section 10.3 in [RFC2181](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt).  That could have been causing the trouble with email.